# Finding NULL column names in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, is there any quick way to find out null column names for a particular record other than using CASE expression?

For eg:

I have one record whose values are like:

```
id|FName|LName|Dept
1 |NULL |Smith|NULL
```

Expected result is: FName, Dept

So, every time I will have only one record and I need to find the list of NULL columns for it.

Comment: Your question is not very clear: Do you have one row in a table, or is this a result set?

Comment: It is a result set

Answer (score 0):

if it's just a result set then you can't do it in sql-server.
but you can use other language making a query tool to do it like below C# code :

```
void Main(){
    var nullColumnsName = GetNullColumnsName("select 1 id,null FName,'Smith' LName ,null Dept");
    Console.WriteLine(nullColumnsName); //result : FName,Dept
}

IEnumerable<string> GetNullColumnsName(string sql)
{
    using (var cnn = Connection)
    {
        if(cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) cnn.Open();
        using(var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand()){
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess|CommandBehavior.SingleResult|CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
            {
                if(reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        var value = reader.GetValue(i);
                        if(value is DBNull)
                            yield return reader.GetName(i); 
                    }
                }
                while (reader.Read()) {};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script. The script:

- opens a cursor over all columns in the table definition
- then, for each column, it queries all values in the column
- if there is no non-null value in the column, it prints the name of the column

```sql
create table tmpTable (id int, FName varchar(32), LName varchar(32), Dept varchar(32))
insert into tmpTable values(1, null, 'Smith', null)
go

declare @column varchar(128)
declare @sql varchar(max)

declare c cursor for
select c.name from sys.tables t join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.name = 'tmpTable'

open c

fetch next from c into @column

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    select @sql = 'if not exists (select * from tmpTable where ' + @column + ' is not null) begin print + ''' + @column + ''' end'
    exec(@sql)

    fetch next from c into @column
end

close c
deallocate c

go


drop table tmpTable
```

For your test case, this is the output of the script:

```
FName
Dept
```

*Note:* This script will work regardless how many rows you have in the table.

**Edit:**

I had written my answer before the following clarification was added "It is a result set". My solution works with a table (as I am querying the system catalogs) and will not cover the clarified scenario (using a result set).

Answer (score 0):

As per your this statement: "every time I will have only one record and I need to find the list of NULL columns for it" 
You can store these values like follows:

> **Column | Values**
>
> FName  |  Null
>
> LName  |  Smith
>
> Dept   |  Null

and I assume that id is the primary key so as per your requirement if you want to store that then you can or if not, it's your choice.

`SELECT Column FROM table
WHERE Values IS NULL;`